# Gmail Create event: show all calendars

Tags: gmail, google-calendar

When I use the Gmail menu function `Create event`, it creates a Google Calendar event from the information of the Gmail conversation. However, as you can see in the screenshots below, it does not show all my available calendars. How can I make all my calendars available?

**Available calendars in Create event dialog:**

[image: Available calendars in Create event dialog]

**All my calendars:**

[image: All my calendars]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new event only main Google Calendar is available. In your case, it looks like "Agenda". Save the event in main calendar and then edit saved event - list of calendars will be available. Choose required calendar from the list. Unfortunately, there are no other ways to do it. Please, see more information by link:
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/calendar/91fFeFYOciA;context-place=topicsearchin/calendar/gmail